# How to edit state provider from another class ? Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

How to edit state provider from another class ? Flutter

```
   socket.on("response", (data) async{
    OrderProvider provider =   Provider.of<OrderProvider>(context);
    print("");
    await provider.changeOrderStatus(OrderStatus.driverFinish);
  });
```

doesn't work like that

Comment: How do you know that it does not work like that?

Comment: i want to call the provider method and update the state from the regular class not inside the widget context pass from the widget

Comment: does not work because there is no change in state

Comment: Then you need to pass an instance of this provider into this class through class constructor or some other method.

Comment: is there a global way? I will have many providers

Comment: Take a look at `get`, It might do what you are looking for: https://pub.dev/packages/get

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not answer your post question, but i will give personal advice in my case. In case you want to call update state from contextless class. You can try to use [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get).

**Example**: To update counter from view, just call function in controller, you dont need to pass context and of course you can call that function in contextless class.

```dart
class Controller extends GetxController{
  var count = 0.obs;
  increment() => count++;
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(context) {
    final Controller c = Get.put(Controller()); // You can declare it in bindding class to use in other classes
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: ),
      body: Center(child: Obx(() => Text("Clicks: ${c.count}"))),
      floatingActionButton:
          FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: c.increment));
  }
}
```

In your case:

```
class YourController extends GetxController{
  changeOrderStatus() => ...;
}

socket.on("response", (data) async {
  var c = Get.find<YourController>();
  print("");
  await c.changeOrderStatus(OrderStatus.driverFinish);
});
```